# java characters upper and lower case

Tags: eclipse

Each character should switch between upper and lower case. My issue is that I cannot get it to work properly. This is what I have so far:

```
        oneLine = br.readLine();
        while (oneLine != null){  // Until the line is not empty (will be when you reach End of file)
            System.out.println (oneLine);    // Print it in screen
            bw.write(oneLine); // Write the line in the output file 
            oneLine = br.readLine(); // read the next line
        }
        int ch;
        while ((ch = br.read()) != -1){

            if (Character.isUpperCase(ch)){
                Character.toLowerCase(ch);

            }
            bw.write(ch);


        }
```

Comment: and does this code work (i.e. compile and runs without runtime errors)? what does it do? why do you think it's doing that?

Comment: `$ tr 'A-Za-z' 'a-zA-Z' < input.txt > output.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.  You had a few problems:

1. You were never actually storing the result of the character case switch.
2. You needed to save the line return with each row
3. I broke out the case switch to make it easier to read

Here's the modified code:

```
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String inputfileName = "input.txt"; // A file with some text in it
    String outputfileName = "output.txt"; // File created by this program
    String oneLine;

    try {
      // Open the input file
      FileReader fr = new FileReader(inputfileName);
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

      // Create the output file
      FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outputfileName);
      BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

      // Read the first line
      oneLine = br.readLine();
      while (oneLine != null) { // Until the line is not empty (will be when you reach End of file)
        String switched = switchCase(oneLine); //switch case
        System.out.println(oneLine + " > "+switched); // Print it in screen
        bw.write(switched+"\n"); // Write the line in the output file
        oneLine = br.readLine(); // read the next line
      }

      // Close the streams
      br.close();
      bw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
  }

  public static String switchCase(String string) {
    String r = "";
    for (char c : string.toCharArray()) {
      if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
        r += Character.toLowerCase(c);
      } else {
        r += Character.toUpperCase(c);
      }
    }
    return r;
  }
```